# Get Text between two tags using nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

My HTML structure is

```
<div class="line">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <h3>Mailing Address</h3>
    2349 Glorem ipsun lorem ipsum  CA 95833<br>
    <br>    

    Phone: 111-111-2111&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fax: 111-511-1111<br>
    <a onfocus="blur()" target="_blank&quot;" href="">some text</a><br>
    <a onfocus="blur()" target="_blank" href="">some address</a><br>
    <div><p></p></div>      

    <h3>Contact(s)</h3>
</div>
```

The HTML page contains several `<div class=line></div>` elements. For each div i need to extract **Phone and Fax** in a array with other data. I tried using

```
doc.css("div#ctl00_cphContent_divBrowseByMember").each do |div|
  div.css("div.line").each do |line|
    line.xpath('//text()[preceding-sibling::br and following-sibling::a]').text.strip
  end
end
```

It returns nothing and returns time out error. 
If I try as 
 `line.xpath('//text()[preceding-sibling::br and following-sibling::a]')[0].text.strip` 
will return same Phone and fax for all other divs. Please suggest any other solution that will help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way:

```
phone, fax = line.text.scan /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/
```

Comment: Depending on who you ask, using regex to parse HTML/XML is a fool's errand. I don't know if you have any control over the HTML of this document, but it would be easier and more consistent to parse if you were dealing with a table row. The clue that this HTML is poorly formated is that it has `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` in it. The multiple `<br>` are also a bad sign more often than not.

Comment: @thekungfuman - true in general but N/A here because line.text is not HTML, and regex *is* the right tool for extracting phone/fax from text

Comment: @pguardiario That's very true. If the HTML was formatted better (a matter of taste, I admit) then it could be parsed with Nokogiri more easily instead of parsing and then regex.